# ATT X86 assembly: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted from gcc

Tags: assembly, gcc-warning, att

I am writing some code in X86 AT&T assembly for a class assignment. Individually I tested all of the functions and they work exactly as intended, but for some reason I get the warning in the title for literally every line in the code. Since the individual functions compiled when placed in their own files and there is nothing besides the functions, I don't really get what is wrong here. Please help.

I am writing it on 14.04 Ubuntu.

```
gcc -m32 -c pstring.s
pstring.s: Assembler messages:
pstring.s: Warning: end of file in string; '"' inserted
pstring.s:3: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:4: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:5: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:6: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:7: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:8: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:9: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:10: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:11: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:12: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:13: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:14: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:15: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:16: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:17: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:18: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:19: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:20: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:21: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:22: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:23: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:24: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:25: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:26: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:27: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:28: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:29: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:30: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:31: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:32: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:33: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:34: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:35: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:36: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:37: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:38: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:39: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:40: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:41: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:42: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:43: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:44: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:45: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:46: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:47: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:48: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:49: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:50: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:51: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:52: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:53: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:54: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:55: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:56: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:57: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:58: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:59: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:60: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:61: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:62: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:63: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:64: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:65: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:66: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:67: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:68: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:69: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:70: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:71: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:72: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:73: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:74: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:75: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:76: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:77: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:78: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:79: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:80: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:81: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:82: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:83: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:84: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:85: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:86: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:87: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:88: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:89: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:90: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:91: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:92: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:93: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:94: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:95: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:96: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:97: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:98: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:99: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:100: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:101: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:102: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:103: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:104: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:105: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:106: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:107: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:108: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:109: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:110: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:111: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:112: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:113: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:114: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:115: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:116: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:117: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:118: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:119: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:120: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:121: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:122: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:123: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:124: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:125: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:126: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:127: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:128: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:129: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:130: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:131: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:132: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:133: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:134: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:135: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:136: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:137: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:138: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:139: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:140: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:141: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:142: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:143: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:144: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:145: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:146: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:147: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:148: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:149: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:150: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:151: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:152: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:153: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:154: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:155: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:156: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:157: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:158: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:159: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:160: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:161: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:162: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:163: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:164: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:165: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:166: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:167: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:168: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:169: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:170: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:171: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:172: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:173: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:174: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:175: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:176: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:177: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:178: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:179: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:180: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:181: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:182: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:183: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:184: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:185: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:186: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:187: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:188: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:189: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:190: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:191: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:192: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:193: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:194: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:195: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:196: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:197: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:198: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:199: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:200: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:201: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:202: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:203: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:204: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:205: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:206: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:207: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:208: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:209: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:210: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:211: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:212: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:213: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:214: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:215: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:216: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:217: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:218: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:219: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:220: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:221: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:222: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:223: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:224: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:225: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:226: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:227: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:228: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:229: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:230: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:231: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:232: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:233: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:234: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
pstring.s:235: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted
```

```
321123242 Nikolay Babkin
    .section    .rodata
error:      .string "invalid input!\n'  # error message.

    .text

    .global pstrlen         #receives a pointer to a pstring as argument.
    .type pstrlen, @function    #returns the length as a byte.
pstrlen:
    pushl   %ebp            #save old FP.
    movl    %esp, %ebp      #set new FP.

    movl    8(%ebp), %eax       #retrieve pointer to pstring.   
    movb    (%eax), %al     #copy the first byte of the argument into %al
    movzbl  %al, %eax       #Zero-fill the other 3 bytes of the register.

    movl    %ebp, %esp      #restore the old stack pointer - release all used memory.
    popl    %ebp            #restore old frame pointer (the caller function frame)
    ret             #return to caller function

    .global replaceChar     #receives a pointer to a pstring, a oldChar byte and a newChar byte as arguments.
    .type replaceChar, @function    #replaces all oldChars with newChars and returns the pointer to the pstring
replaceChar:
    pushl   %ebp            #save old FP
    movl    %esp, %ebp      #set new FP

    pushl   %ebx            #save %ebx on stack

    movl    8(%ebp), %eax       #get the pstring pointer from the stack.
    movb    (%eax), %bh     #retrieved the len of the pstring
    addl    $1, %eax        #align the pointer to point to the string itself
    movl    12(%ebp), %ecx      #get the oldChar argument.
    movb    %cl, %dl        #store oldChar in %dl
    movl    16(%ebp), %ecx      #get the newChar argument.
    movb    %cl, %dh        #store newChar in %dh

    movb    $0, %bl         #initialize count register to 1.

    rcTEST:
    cmpb    %bh, %bl        #Test
    je  rcDONE          #if Test: goto done

    rcLOOP:             #loop label
    cmpb    %dl, (%eax)     #compare the current byte to the oldChar byte
    je  rcCHANGE        #jump to change the oldChar.
    rcINCREMENT:            #label for incrementing the current char and the count variable.
    add $1, %bl         #increment the count
    add $1, %eax        #increment the string pointer one byte.
    jmp rcTEST          #Don't want no infinite loops causing segmentation faults, do we?
    rcCHANGE:
    movb    %dh, (%eax)     #overwrite the oldChar with a newChar
    jmp rcINCREMENT     #move on with the loop mechanism

    rcDONE:
    mov 8(%ebp), %eax       #set return value to be the pstring pointer.
    popl    %ebx            #restore %ebx register.
    movl    %ebp, %esp      #restore the old stack pointer - release all used memory.
    popl    %ebp            #restore old frame pointer (the caller function frame)
    ret             #return to caller function

    .global pstrijcpy
    .type   pstrijcpy, @function
pstrijcpy:
    pushl   %ebp            #save old FP
    movl    %esp, %ebp      #set new FP
#using eax, ebx, ech, edx, 
    pushl   %ebx            #back %ebx up.

    movl    16(%ebp), %eax      #the dword with i
    movb    %al, %bl        #store i in %bl
    movl    20(%ebp), %eax      #the dword with j
    movb    %al, %bh        #store j in %bh
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax       #initialize eax to dst ptr.
    movb    (%eax), %dh     #%dh <- dst.len
    addl    $1, %eax        #advance %eax by one byte to the string
    movl    12(%ebp), %ecx      #initialize ecx to src ptr.
    mov (%ecx), %dl     #%dl <- src.len
    addl    $1, %ecx        #advance %ecx by one byte to the string

    cmpb    %dl, %bl        #i-src.len
    jg  cpyERROR        #if >: goto error
    cmp %dl, %bh        #j-src.len
    jg  cpyERROR        #if >: goto error
    cmpb    %dh, %bl        #i-dst.len
    jg  cpyERROR        #if >: goto error
    cmp %dh, %bh        #j-dst.len
    jg  cpyERROR        #if >: goto error

    #now I will add i to the pointers that point to the strings.
    push    %edx            #back edx up
    movzbl  %bl, %edx       #apparently I can use 'movl %bl, %eax', so I did this.
    addl    %edx, %eax      #advance dst to ith character
    addl    %edx, %ecx      #advance src to ith character
    popl    %edx            #restore edx

    cpyTEST:
    cmpb    %bh, %bl        #compare i with j
    jg  cpyDONE         #once i is greater than j, we are done.

    cpyLOOP:
    movb    (%ecx), %dl     #Since I already checked that i and j <= the lengths, I can use them
    movb    %dl, (%eax)     #Move byte from src to dst.
    addl    $1, %ecx        #Increment src to next byte
    addl    $1, %eax        #Increment dst to next byte
    addl    $1, %ebx        #Increment i by 1.
    jmp cpyTEST         #goto test

    cpyERROR:           #don't need to back registers up.
    pushl   $error          #push the message to be printed.
    call    printf          #use printf to print error message

    cpyDONE:
    popl    %ebx            #restore %ebx
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax       #set return value to be dst pointer.
    movl    %ebp, %esp      #restore the old stack pointer - release all used memory.
    popl    %ebp            #restore old frame pointer (the caller function frame)
    ret             #return to caller function

    .global swapCase        #swaps the cases of the string.
    .type   swapCase, @function
swapCase:
    pushl   %ebp            #save old FP
    movl    %esp, %ebp      #set new FP

    movl    8(%ebp), %eax       #get pointer to pstring
    movb    (%eax), %cl     #get length of pstring
    addl    $1, %eax        #move pointer to string itself

    scLTEST:            #loop condition.
    cmpb    $0, %cl         #compare length with 0
    je  scDONE          #if length is zero, goto done
    jmp scLOOP          #else: goto loop

    scLOOP:
    cmpb    $97, (%eax)     #compares first byte of string with 'a'.
    jge scTRYLOWER      #byte is lowercase-possible.
    cmpb    $90, (%eax)     #compares first byte of string with 'Z'.
    jle scTRYUPPER      #byte is uppercase-possible.
    jmp scINC           #byte is between 65 and 97, so not a letter.

    scTRYUPPER:         #checking if byte is really upper-case.
    cmpb    $65, (%eax)     #compare byte with 'A'.
    jge scCHANGETOLOWER     #if byte is 'A' or after, it is upper-case, so change to lower-case.
    jmp scINC           #otherwise, it is below 'A' and is thus not a letter.

    scTRYLOWER:
    cmpb    $122, (%eax)        #compare byte with 'z'.
    jle scCHANGETOUPPER     #if it is before or at 'z', it is a lower-case letter.
    jmp scINC           #otherwise, it is over 'z' and not a letter.

    scCHANGETOUPPER:
    subb    $32, (%eax)     #reduce the byte from range [97,122] to [65,90]
    jmp scINC

    scCHANGETOLOWER:
    addb    $32, (%eax)     #increase the byte to range [97,122] from [65,90]
    #jmp    scINC           #for now, the jump is not necessary since the increment stage is already after it.

    scINC:
    addl    $1, %eax        #increment %eax to next byte
    decb    %cl         #decrement counter
    jmp scLTEST         #end current loop iteration

    scDONE:
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax       #set return value to pointer to pstring.
    movl    %ebp, %esp      #restore old stack pointer
    popl    %ebp            #restore old FP
    ret             #return to caller function

    .global pstrijcmp       #compares pstring1 and pstring 2 in range i to j.
    .type   pstrijcmp, @function    #returns -1 if pstring1 < pstring2, 0 if equal and 1 if greater. -2 is error value.
pstrijcmp:
    pushl   %ebp            #save old FP
    movl    %esp, %ebp      #set new FP

    pushl   %ebx            #back %ebx up.

    movl    16(%ebp), %eax      #retrieve the dword with i.
    movb    %al, %ch        #set %ch to be i.
    movl    20(%ebp), %eax      #retrieve the dword with j.
    movb    %al, %cl        #set %cl to be j.

    movl    8(%ebp), %eax       #set pstring1ptr into eax.
    movl    12(%ebp), %edx      #set pstring2ptr into edx.

    cmpb    (%eax), %ch     #i-str1.len
    jg  cmpERROR        #if i>len: goto error
    cmp (%eax), %cl     #j-str1.len
    jg  cmpERROR        #if jlen>: goto error
    cmpb    (%edx), %ch     #i-str2.len
    jg  cmpERROR        #if i>len2: goto error
    cmp (%edx), %cl     #j-str2.len
    jg  cmpERROR        #if j>len2: goto error

    incl    %eax            #increment eax to get past the length byte
    incl    %edx            #increment edx to get past the length byte

    cmpTEST:
    cmpb    %cl, %ch        #compare i with j
    jg  cmpPREDONE          #goto done once i>j
    #jmp    cmpLOOP         #else: goto loop

    cmpLOOP:
    movb    (%eax), %bl     #take current str1 byte into %bl
    cmpb    %bl, (%edx)     #compare %bl with first %edx byte
    je  cmpINC          #if same: increment phase.
    jl  cmpLESS         #str1 is before str2 lexicographically.
    movl    $1, %eax        #set return value to 1.
    jmp cmpDONE         #done.

    cmpLESS:
    movl    $-1, %eax       #set return value to -1
    jmp cmpDONE         #done

    cmpINC:
    incl    %eax            #increment str1 pointer.
    incl    %edx            #increment str2 pointer.
    incb    %ch         #i++
    jmp cmpTEST         #current loop iteration is over.

    cmpERROR:           #don't need to back registers up.
    pushl   $error          #push the message to be printed.
    call    printf          #use printf to print error message
    movl    $-2, %eax       #set return value to -2
    jmp cmpDONE

    cmpPREDONE:
    movl    $0, %eax        #set return value to 0.

    cmpDONE:
    popl    %ebx            #restore old %ebx
    movl    %ebp, %esp      #restore old stack pointer
    popl    %ebp            #restore old FP
    ret             #return to caller function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is on line 3, like the message says.  You have `"string'` instead of `"string"`.  (Note the closing quote).

Also, comments like "Test" on a `cmpb` instruction are useless.  You should be commenting *why* the code does what it does, or at least what data is involved.  I know it's tempting to write comments that read like an insn ref manual, but don't.

`movb    $0, %bl         #initialize count register to 1.` was particularly amusing.

Also, indent your code one more level than your labels, so they stand out.

The [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) wiki has lots of good links, btw.

Comment: Thanks for the patient response. And yeah, the comments were not particularly inspired - my excuse it that I had bigger headaches  to deal with(sometimes literally) and I'm sticking with it. The count register one was just bad though, probably remained from some change or another. Overall, thanks, gonna leaf through that wiki once I manage to free up some time.